# Ignite Questions about "qryexe"

Tags: java, ignite

1. I figured out "qryfldexe" is able to query cross caches with multiple "join", but couldn't figure out if "qryexe" also has a way to achieve that.
2. The reason of having desire from question 1 is because "qryexe" returns items in key value fashion, but "qryfldexe" returns items in an array that only has values in each array item. Is there a java lib to load the type of json returned by "qryfldexe" into a json object based on the fields metadata in the end(or beginning) of the json payload?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. No, `qryexe` only works on a single cache (same as its Java counterpart, `SqlQuery`).
2. There is no Java client for Ignite REST API as far as I know, but there is also a more efficient [Thin Client Protocol](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/IEP-9+Thin+Client+Protocol) and a work-in-progress Java client for it (see [this mailing list thread](http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/Thin-client-Java-bindings-td26107.html) with description and some links).